# How to move forward with rotationg head

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to move forward like this

```
float speed = 40;

this.transform.Translate(0,0,speed/50);
```

It works well when character's face is looking horizontally(y=0)

However when character's face is looking down,

Somehow, It goes down through the terrain.

Is there any good way to move horizontally even character's face is looking down??

Answer (score 0):

**If the GameObject the script is attached to is passing through the terrain (to find out look in the scene view with the object selected and see if its position is inside the terrain):**

transform.Translate moves the position of a GameObject in the direction specified even if there is an object with a collider in the way such as terrain.
If you want to move an object with collision detection you should think about using a [Rigidbody](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html) or [CharacterController](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html).

**If the camera is seeing through the terrain even though the camera is not inside the terrain (to find out look in the scene view with the camera selected and see if its position is inside the terrain):**

It is possible that the value of the camera's near [clipping plane](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Camera.html) is too large. The camera's clipping planes tell Unity at what distances to start and stop rendering geometry. The far clipping plane tells Unity at what distance away from the camera to stop rendering geometry and the near clipping plane tells Unity at what distance from the camera to start rendering geometry. Any geometry within the two values is rendered and any geometry outside the two values is not. To stop the camera seeing through the terrain you could try lowering the value of the near clipping plane, to have geometry closer to the camera rendered or move the camera further away from the terrain.